# PHP Slim 3 Framework - Why does routing not automatically load controller files?

Tags: php, slim-3

I registering a controller with the container, but it seems not working because it doesn't match to the correct location.

\web\index.php

```
<?php


require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


// Instantiate the app
 $app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true] ]);


$app->get('/', 'App\controllers\HomeController:home'); 


// Run!
$app->run();
```

\web\App\controllers\HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\controllers\HomeController; 

class HomeController
{
   protected $container;

   // constructor receives container instance
   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
   }

   public function home($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
   }

   public function contact($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
   }
}
```

Because it show Slim Application Error:

Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details
Type: RuntimeException
Message: Callable App\controllers\HomeController does not exist
File: /Users/feikeq/Desktop/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
Line: 90

My project folder structure:

```
\web 
　　index.php
    \App 
　　　　\controllers 
　　　　　　HomeController.php 
　　\vendor
```

Why is it wrong? Thk

Comment: Can you show us your `composer.json` file content?

Comment: Be sure to add the "composer.json" configuration? I want to be simpler, so development has become more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change namespase  `App\controllers\HomeController` to `App\controllers` into `\web\App\controllers\HomeController.php`
2. Modify \web\index.php

   ```
   <?php
   require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   // Instantiate the app
   $app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true] ]);
   $container = $app->getContainer();
   $container['App\controllers\HomeController'] = function ($c) {
       return new App\controllers\HomeController($c);
   };
   $app->get('/', 'App\controllers\HomeController:home'); 
   // Run!
   $app->run();
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the error still exists:
 
Type: Error
Message: Class 'App\controllers\HomeController' not found
Line: 7

Comment: you need to run the autoload generator again with `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Slim should be able to create `HomeController` class without registering it in dependency container because its constructor accepts only one parameter, which is, container instance. Problem mostly because of directory structure that does not match with PSR-4 autoload.